# Discord.js v14 Sending Message in Separate Channel Not Working

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I am creating a command, where on a button click it is supposed to send a message in a specific channel.

To achieve this, I have used the code given in the discord.js documentations faq;

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('id');
channel.send('content');
```

However, on clicking the button, the console gives the following error;

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

I'm not very well versed at discord.js whatsoever, so I have no idea what to do.

Here's the full code for the button interaction;

```
   const filter = i => i.customId === 'accept' && i.member.roles.cache.has('1111582370265563200');
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter });
    collector.on('collect', async i => {
        if (i.customId === 'accept'){
         accept.setDisabled(true)
            const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1111616693358301237');
            channel.send({embeds: [embedAccept]});
         i.update({embeds: [yesembed]});
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your `client` is defined properly? Can you attach a snippet with the code declaring it?

Comment: @Crytek1012 The client isn't actually defined in this file but in the index.js. In this file is have just used `const { client } = require('discord.js');` since I am not sure how to define client otherwise without creating a new client. Would that be the issue? If so, do you know how I could declare it in this file without creating a new client?

Comment: This would definitely be the issue here. You need to use the same `client` that you previously declared in your `index.js` file.
I recommend you check the docs and code a command handler, which will solve your issue and simplify your work in the long run.
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files

Comment: @Crytek1012 I am already using a command handler?

Comment: Can you attach the command's full code then?

Comment: Yes here is an abridged version of the code;
https://codeshare.io/BAKMZL

Comment: I believe you can solve the issue by using `interaction.client.channels.cache.get('1111616693358301237');`

Comment: Welcome! I have left an answer in order for whoever finds this issue to get a clearer answer. If you wish you can mark it as accepted.
Have a good coding sessions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to access the `channels` property of an undefined `client`.

For slash commands, you can access your client instance by using `interaction.client`.

```
const channel = interaction.client.channels.cache.get('1111616693358301237');
```